# Getting error page when seeing the replies on chat page

Tags: bug, chat

I am getting an error page when I click to `replies` tab to see the replies that I given.

Reference picture shown here

> [image]

When I clicked here, something bad happened and redirect to error page which look like this.

> [image]

Comment: [meta-tag:status-norepro] here.

Comment: @sachin, do you frequent the chat rooms? I ask because it takes me 10 to 12 seconds after clicking "replies" for the page to load, at which point it shows two replies from quite a while ago. In fact, it takes just as long every time I click—suggesting there's no caching, even. I wonder if in your case, there are a lot of logs from you being a frequent user in chat, but the last time someone replied to you by your handle (@sachin) was a long time ago, and the query times out.

Comment: @acheong87 No, I'm not frequent to the chat room. I used the chat room couple of month ago.

Comment: This should no longer happen, can you confirm?

Comment: @balpha Yes it's working fine now. Can you please share that what were the problem?